# MVC jquery ajax call serialize always empty

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send data from a form to my controller in the back end using jquery ajax.  When I serialize the form it is always empty.  When I do an alert($("#formMain").serialize()) its always empty.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

html:

```
<form id="formMain">
    Date: <input type="text" id="DateSelected" style="width:95px;" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="javascript: return SubmitForm();" />
</form>


function SubmitForm() {
        alert($("#formMain").serialize());
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Submit",
                data: $("#formMain").serialize()
            });

            return false;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a name attribute in your input field

Comment: Wow.. thats all that was.  Thanks for finding the miss.